# How do native Javascript functions work in V8?

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome, v8, chromium

I am trying to figure out how some Javascript native functions and operators (shorthand functions) are implemented under the hood in Chrome's V8. In particular, I'm trying to understand how the Unary (-) operation works.

I have found the code for `unary operators` in V8 [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/10a801f12bb9d482b5dcd4c5856ba7920cc8c72a/src/compiler/typer.cc#L1004)

Could someone explain what's happening here:

```
Type* Typer::Visitor::JSTypeOfTyper(Type* type, Typer* t) {
  Factory* const f = t->isolate()->factory();
  if (type->Is(Type::Boolean())) {
    return Type::Constant(f->boolean_string(), t->zone());
  } else if (type->Is(Type::Number())) {
    return Type::Constant(f->number_string(), t->zone());
  } else if (type->Is(Type::String())) {
    return Type::Constant(f->string_string(), t->zone());
  } else if (type->Is(Type::Symbol())) {
    return Type::Constant(f->symbol_string(), t->zone());
  } else if (type->Is(Type::Union(Type::Undefined(), Type::OtherUndetectable(),
                                  t->zone()))) {
    return Type::Constant(f->undefined_string(), t->zone());
  } else if (type->Is(Type::Null())) {
    return Type::Constant(f->object_string(), t->zone());
  } else if (type->Is(Type::Function())) {
    return Type::Constant(f->function_string(), t->zone());
  } else if (type->IsConstant()) {
    return Type::Constant(
        Object::TypeOf(t->isolate(), type->AsConstant()->Value()), t->zone());
  }
  return Type::InternalizedString();
}


Type* Typer::Visitor::TypeJSTypeOf(Node* node) {
  return TypeUnaryOp(node, JSTypeOfTyper);
}
```

I have absolutely no background on C++, as I'm a web developer, so I can't seem to understand what's happening. Thanks!

Comment: I guess what without goog knowledge of v8 architecture no one could explain what's happening here. Why exactly do you want to dig so deep?

Comment: The problem here that this question cannot be answered without deep knowledge of the v8 implementation. It is clear that the code identifies the type of `type` and takes a corresponding representation of it. For more explanation maybe contact a developer, or study the documentation https://v8docs.nodesource.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `-` is turned into multiplication by `-1`.

src/parsing/parser.cc

```
  // The same idea for '-foo' => 'foo*(-1)'.
  if (op == Token::SUB) {
    return factory()->NewBinaryOperation(
         Token::MUL, expression, factory()->NewNumberLiteral(-1, pos), pos);
  }
```

Do you want to say in more detail what you want to understand about `-`?

Comment: That looks like what I was looking for. Could you link me to the LOC?

Comment: It's in `src/parsing/parser.cc` line 466.